# Prob. 20, Sec. 1.1 in Strang's intro to Linear Algebra, 4th ed: Given three vectorss, what combination will lie inside or on the triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis, plane-geometry

Let $u$, $v$, and $w$ be any three non-coplanar vectors emanating from the origin of the three-dimensional Euclidean space. Let $x = au + bv + cw$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are scalars. Then what is the necessary and sufficient condition (on $a$, $b$, and $c$) for the head of $x$ to lie

(i) in the interior

(ii) on the boundary

of the triangle determined by $u$, $v$, and $w$?

My effort:

The equation of the plane determined by the head points of $u$, $v$, and $w$ is $$ (y - u) \cdot (y-v) \times (y-w) = 0.$$ 
Am I right?

So in either case we must have 
$$ (x - u) \cdot (x-v) \times (x-w) = 0.$$ 
Or, 
$$ [ (a-1) u + bv + cw ] \cdot [ au + (b-1)v + cw ] \times [ au + bv + (c-1)w ] = 0.$$
The last equation simplifies to
$$ (a + b + c -1 ) u \cdot v \times w = 0.$$
But as $u$, $v$, and $w$ are non-coplanar, so $$ u \cdot v \times w \neq 0,$$
and therefore $$a+b+c=1.$$ 
Am I right?

What next?

Comment: Yes you are right. For part (i) you have the additional requirement that $a,b,c>0$ and for (ii) in addition to these requrements you also have that at least one of $a,b,c$ is zero

Comment: @DavidQuinn thank you for your comment, but I'd be grateful if you could write out a detailed answer, giving a rigorous proof of your assertions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the rigor you need, but I can try:

Consider the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$ passing by the origin of coordinates. A plane splits the space in two parts. Now, $cw$ with $c>0$ is in one of the parts, obviously, the same the triangle is. With $c<0$ $cw$ points to the other part, so, $au+bv+cw$ with $c<0$ is in the triangle's exterior. Name the half space the triangle is as "positive". Analogously for the other two planes ($u$ with $w$ and $v$ with $w$). So $a,b,c\ge 0$ is a necessary condition. It is a sufficient condition too: the triangle is into the intersection of the three positive half spaces considered above

One of the sides of the triangle is into the plane $mu+nv=0$, so if $au+bv=0$ is in that side. $c=0$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for the point to be in that side. Analogously for the other sides.